# How do I convert a c++ string to a .NET String^?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2005, string, type-conversion

I've been trying to figure out how to convert a string to a String in Visual Studio 2005 with no luck.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#using <System.dll>
using namespace System;

string test = "a test string";
```

So I'm trying to convert test into a String^ to use inside other .NET classes, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not totally sure... I'm just learning c++ now, so I don't know exactly. I only came across String^ in .NET so far, so my knowledge of managed types is definitely lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String^ str = gcnew String(test)
```

Comment: You missed the `c_str()` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for MS reference